# How do I remove unnecessary values from list view?

Tags: android, listview

I am unable to remove these top two value, I am reading mp3 files from res folder and showing it here. last three files are the name of songs but the top two are not needed.Help me on how to remove them. This is my code as I am reading values from res and showing to ListView and then playing that audio:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> songNames;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Mylistview);
        songNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
        list.clear();
        for(Field f : fields)
            try {

                list.add(f.getName());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                //     songNames.add(getResources().getClass(R.raw.song1));
                //  songNames.add(getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.raw.song2));
                // songNames.add(getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.raw.song3));


                final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        Uri mp3 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/"
                                + list.get(position));
                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        try {
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),mp3);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);

                    }
                });

            }

    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    };

}
```

[image]

Comment: Show your code. Edit your question add more code! We can not see whats going on without the code!

Comment: Yes i added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `for (Field f : fields)`, just write:

```
for (int i = 2; i < fields.length; i++) {
    Field f = fields[i];
```

And add a closing curly bracket `}` after the try-catch block.

Comment: Short of editing your raw data, I don't think that there is a better way than not adding the list items you don't want.